# How to map URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My local site have project folder `http://127.0.0.1/myproject/index.php`. I want to be able to map its URL so if someone enters `http://127.0.0.1/myproject/service`, it should display the same content or perform the same functionality as index.php does.

I tried some example on different site but couldn't get it done.

What I tried so far is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\myproject\service$ $index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/
RewriteRule service index.php [L,QSA]
```

First, setup the base to rewrite. In the rule, all paths are now **relative** to the base, not absolute.

The flag `L` denotes no other rules should be applied.

The flag `QSA` denotes that the query string should be appended.

For more information: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

I would even go as far as to say, check what Wordpress is giving you:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /myproject/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```